# PHP - Amazon AWS SES - How to verify the status of a domain name

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've added a new domain name in the list of "verified domain names", update the DNS and now I want to verify through the API (PHP SDK actually ) if the domain names has been marked as verified by aws .   So far I have this

```
function get_verified_status($domain, $key, $secret) {
// Instantiate the client with your AWS credentials
        $ses = SesClient::factory(array(
                    'key'     => $key,
                    'secret'  => $secret,
                    'region'  => Region::US_EAST_1
                ));
print_r($domain);
echo "response";
$response = $ses->GetIdentityVerificationAttributes($domain);
#$response = $ses->list_verified_email_addresses();

//get_identity_verification_attributes
        return $response;
}
```

The response is (running from cli )

php test.php

```
Array
(
    [0] => appi.com
    [1] => acs.com
)
responsePHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Service\Exception\ValidationException' with message 'Validation errors: [Identities] is a required array: A list of identities.' in /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php:376
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php(272): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->validate()
#1 /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(193): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->prepare()
#2 /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php(162): Guzzle\Service\Client->execute(Object(Aws\Common\Command\QueryCommand))
#3 /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php(213): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->execute()
#4 /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(93): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->getResult()
#5 /var/www/html/s3/vendo in /var/www/html/s3/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php on line 376
```

I don't understand why I get this error because I pass an array as can be seen in the print. I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

According to the [AWS SDK for PHP API docs for GetIdentityVerificationAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_getIdentityVerificationAttributes), the structure of the input parameters dictates that you should call the method like this:

```
$result = $ses->getIdentityVerificationAttributes(array(
    'Identities' => $domains
));

print_r($result->toArray());
```

Hope that helps!